# TypeError: ctx.sls.service.package.include.push is not a function

Tags: yaml, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm trying to include static files with my lambda function.  I am receiving the this error when trying to deploy:

> TypeError: ctx.sls.service.package.include.push is not a function

This is the relevant part of my serverless.yml.

```
package:
  include: ../shared/static/**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was `package.include` expects an array, but I passed it a string.  In yaml, an array (called a sequence) is denoted with a new line, a dash, and a space for each element.

```
package:
  include: 
    - ../shared/templates/**
```

[YAML docs on defining sequences](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2797382)